# Creating tables using for loop and naming them based on the instance in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to optimize my code where I create a table between a row and the rest of the columns in the data set using the `table()` function.

Dummy Code:

```
set.seed(50)
n = 7
dat <- data.frame(first_column  = c(1:n),
second_column = c(sample(1:3, n,replace = TRUE)),
third_column  = c(sample(1:3, n,,replace = TRUE)),
fourth_column = c(sample(1:3, n,replace = TRUE)),
fifth_column  = c(sample(1:3, n,replace = TRUE))
)
dat

for(i in dat[2:5]){
table <- paste("R",i , "table", sep = "_")
table <- assign(table, table(dat$first_column, as.factor(i)))
print(table)
```

I am having an issue where the tables generated are not named after the column they are generated with. They are instead named after the first variable. Is there a way to specify the column title when naming the table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can use `names()`

Comment: we should always avoid using `assign`, specially if we are already assigning something with the assignment operator `<-`. `y <- assign(x)` is very confusing to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `purrr::map` to loop through `dat` (removing the first column beforehand). I recommend this method also because it keeps the output in a tidy list instead of assigning all values to the global environment, which looks cleaner and much safer

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(select(dat, -1), ~table(dat$first_column, unname(.x)))

$second_column
   
    2 3
  1 0 1
  2 0 1
  3 0 1
  4 1 0
  5 1 0
  6 0 1
  7 0 1

$third_column
   
    1 2 3
  1 0 1 0
  2 0 0 1
  3 1 0 0
  4 1 0 0
  5 0 0 1
  6 0 1 0
  7 0 0 1

$fourth_column
   
    1 2 3
  1 1 0 0
  2 0 1 0
  3 0 0 1
  4 1 0 0
  5 1 0 0
  6 0 1 0
  7 0 1 0

$fifth_column
   
    1 2 3
  1 1 0 0
  2 0 1 0
  3 1 0 0
  4 0 1 0
  5 1 0 0
  6 0 1 0
  7 0 0 1
```